# WSOD after upgrading to 3.1

Tags: plugins, themes, upgrade

I installed the new wordpress 3.1, but it gave me some problems and I had
restore everything, you'd know it help me?
Practically after updating the site was completely white and I could not
access the dashboard. I do not know if it's in conflict with some plugin or theme
... but I do not risk coming back to update: (
Can you help me? www.talkischeap.it

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after upgrading my local environment (wordpress/xamp).
I ran http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/upgrade.php and then I could get back in to the admin.
I then had to update the database and upgrade to 3.1 again.
After that all seems to be fine.

Hope it helps you too!

Comment: so you think I should try to update again?

Comment: It´s up to you in the end, but I would give it a try. It won´t hurt, and you want to get to 3.1 eventually.

Comment: It can hurt badly, so make sure you backup every thing you can before any upgrade/update.